# Why is my internal API call not waiting for response?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have an Express.js / Node.js API project where I am calling a endpoint that depends on an internal async function.

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

async function getToken() {
  fetch("www.example.com", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(userName + ':' + password),
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json)
      return { response_code: 200, response: json }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return { response_code: 500 }
    })
}

router.get('/getAll', async (req, res) => {
  var token = await getToken()
  console.log(token)
  res.status(200).json({'response': token})
})
```

What I want here is that function `getToken()` should be able to be called from multiple endpoints. For example, when `/getAll` endpoint is called, it gets the token from `getToken()` first and then proceeds with its own logic. For this I am using `await` keyword.

But when I call the `/getAll` endpoint, I get `undefined` in the return value of `await getToken()`. I have checked using `console.log()` and I can see that the `console` in `/getAll` gets called first, and **after that** I get the actual token value that is being logged from inside `async function getToken()`.

Why is this happening and what can I change to get the token value from my function?

Comment: There's no point making a function async if it doesn't await anything. Right now getToken returns a promise of undefined _totally unconnected_ from the fetch promise.

Comment: you are returning a value in your `getToken()` function, you need to return the result of a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code, you have a plain function, meaning that it ends the function and gets out, as it awaits for nothing and returns nothing... as you are returning only inside something that will occur later in time (after the fetch is done, it could be after 0.0001s or 10s, you don't know)

```
async function getToken() {
  fetch("www.example.com", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(userName + ':' + password),
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      return { response_code: 200, response: json }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return { response_code: 500 }
    })

    // returns right here, always...
}
```

to make it working you need to tell the function that you are returning a result, for example

```
function getToken() {
  return fetch("www.example.com", { // we're asking the function to return it's result
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(userName + ':' + password),
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      return { response_code: 200, response: json }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return { response_code: 500 }
    })
}
```

**Important note when using fetch()**

one thing you should be aware is that you're `catch` is in the wrong place, as you are calling  `.then(response => response.json())` and the function could have thrown before this call, and you would have no `response` at all

here's a nice video of what is happening and how you can improve it
https://twitter.com/Steve8708/status/1611437686958739456?lang=en

---

a simple live working example

```js
function getToken() {
  return fetch("https://holidays.coding.garden", {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      return { response_code: 200 }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return { response_code: 500 }
    })
}

(async () => {

    console.time('fetch')

    console.log('here 1')
    const result = await getToken()
    console.log('here 2', result)

    console.timeEnd('fetch')
    
})()
```